# How do you use the loop index as argument of mean() function?

Tags: r

I have many vectors called *var1*, *var2*, *var3*, etc.

I want to get the mean of these vector with a loop, but I cannot manage to use the loop index inside the *mean( )* function.

For example I have tried this:

```
    while (i<100) { 

        matrix[i,1] <- mean(paste0("var",i))
        i <- i + 1
      }
```

But the *mean( )* function does not accept *paste0( )* as a variable.

Can you help me?

Comment: Use something like eval(parse(text=paste("var",i,sep=""))) see https://goodscienceblog.wordpress.com/2016/12/02/a-very-useful-function-eval-parse-text-paste/ .

Comment: @Jesper's answer is a good one.  However, this problem should convince you to use a different data structure for storing your vectors.  Any environment-like structure will work, such as a list or, if all vectors have the same size, an array or data frame object.  In the latter case you can obtain the means of all the vectors in one swoop using `rowMeans` or `colMeans` and in the former case *via* `lapply`.